# bash script, control processes with stdin/stdout

Tags: bash, shell, process-control

Please help to advise how to use bash to catch the sub-process's stdout and send character to sub-process's stdin.

For example, use bash to control 10 videos convert by ffmpeg process, bash code needs to watch each ffmpeg process's stdout then decides if send the stdin command `[+]`/`[-]`/`[c]`/`[q]` or others command to control ffmpeg

the covert job would be something like

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_n -c copy -f flv out_n.flv 2>&1 | grep "[MY_PATTERN]"
```

only when [MY_PATTERN] occurs this job shows word on it's stdout. 
I would like to use bash code to catch the job's stdout, do some decision according to the line included MY_PATTERN then feed command into the job's stdin.
I guess I need to active new shell by bash to execute the job and interact its stdin/stdout. But how to ?

Comment: the example now expresses not only the quit action but also other actions that depend on MY_PATTERN

Answer (score 0):

If I inderstood the question correct, you need to use `grep -q "MY_PATTERN"`.  This would send a `SIGPIPE` to the `ffmpeg` process as soon as the pattern is matched.

The following should work for you:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT_n -c copy -f flv out_n.flv 2>&1 | grep -q "[MY_PATTERN]" && some_command
```

`some_command` would be executed as soon as the pattern is matched.

Comment: Thank your reply, for me this solution has 2 problems. Firstly the MY_PATTERN may a regular expression that need following detection and select case in bash. Secondly the action is to stop ffmpeg by enter [q] in stdin

Comment: this solution the some_command would be executed when ffmpeg finish, but what I try to achieve is to stop ffmpeg

Comment: @Yehudi Did you try it?  As mentioned above, this would send a `SIGPIPE` to `ffmpeg`.  That should stop it as soon as the pattern is found.

Comment: Hi devnull, you are right, grep -q "[MY_PATTERN]" would stop the ffmpeg. But I hope to do some decision (one of the decision is to stop ffmpeg) according to the line included MY_PATTERN. Do you think it's possible to handle subprocess's stdin/stdout on bash?

Comment: @Yehudi It might help if you update the question with scenarios.

Comment: @Yehudi No, it isn't.  Examples might help.

Comment: modify again, the example now express not only the `quit` action but also other actions that depend on MY_PATTERN.